# Custom configuration files in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.3

I have a CakePHP 3.3.14 application where I've created 2 subdirectories, `webroot/data/downloads/` and `webroot/data/master`

I want to put these paths in a custom configuration file and reference them in a Controller. But I can't see how to do this.

I've followed the [documentation on Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html) but it's not very clear.

So what I've done:

- Created `config/my_config.php`
- The above file defines an array:

  ```
  return [ 'downloadsPath' => 'webroot/data/downloads/', 'masterPath' => 'webroot/data/master/' ];
  ```
- In `config/bootstrap.php` I've put: `Configure::load('my_config', 'default');`

How do I then use this in a Controller? If I put `Configure::read('my_config.masterPath');` it gives an error saying: **Class 'App\Controller\Configure' not found**

If I add `use Cake\Core\Configure;` to the top of my Controller, that clears the error but the return value is `null`:

```
debug(Configure::read('my_config.masterPath')); // null
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear about this section that even contains examples? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#loading-configuration-files

Comment: Well, if you reference what I've actually written above with what's written there, it is quite unclear as to where I'm going wrong in my opinion. That's why I've posted the question...

Comment: Your read call is simply wrong. `'my_config.masterPath'`no idea from where you've got the idea that you have to put the file name in front. `masterPath` should work.

Comment: The reason I was doing it like that is because the way I (mis)understood the documentation was that you had to tell it *which* config file the value was specified in. For example if you had 3 config files and they all had an array key `masterPath` that would surely present some problem? Thanks for the advice though, I can see the error of my ways..

Answer (score 7):

Loading another config file just extends the default `App.config`. So just use `\Cake\Core\Configure::read('masterPath')` and you are good.

**EDIT**

If it is your goal to have different config paths you could do it like this:

```
// my_config.php
return [
    'MyConfig' => [
        'masterPath' => '...',
        ...
    ]
];
```

Then use the config like this:

```
<?= \Cake\Core\Configure::read('MyConfig.masterPath') ?>
```

Comment: Also you need to add `Configure::load('my_config', 'default');` in `bootstrap.php`

Comment: how can i write into this file ?

Comment: @ManojKumar https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#writing-configuration-data